# Fragment with Tabs in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

I have 2 fragments FragmentA and FragmentB. FragmentA is on top of FragmentB. Now I want to add tabs on FragmentB. Please Help.
My code so far :-

layout/fragmentA.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Top Fragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

layout/fragmentB.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F5F6CE"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <include 
                    android:id="@+id/tabdata1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    layout=“@layout/tabdata1_view"/>

                <include 
                    android:id="@+id/tabdata2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    layout=“@layout/tabdata2_view"
                    />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

FragmentB.java

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment{

    TabHost myTabHost;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2_layout, container, false);

        myTabHost = (TabHost) getView().findViewById(R.id.tabhost)

        return rootView;

    }

}
```

Error:-

The line “`myTabHost = (TabHost) getView().findViewById(R.id.tabhost)`”gives an error as it cannot find tabhost.

Please suggest a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
myTabHost = (TabHost) rootview.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
```

This should remove the error which you are facing now

Answer (score 0):

That's because until you return from onCreateView, the fragment does not actually have a view yet. You just need to call findViewById relative to rootView. Like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2_layout, container, false);

    myTabHost = (TabHost) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabhost)

    return rootView;

}
```